# Can I create a role from inside a select through a batch script?

Tags: postgresql

I know the question seems complex, but I will explain it better here.

I have a select that connects to and outputs the names of the connected databases in a cluster and I would like to create a role (mentioning the name of the database) inside each database.

This is my select:

```
select '\c '||t1.datname||chr(10)||'
SELECT ''Database: ''||current_database();
SELECT '' create role "'||t1.datname||'_connect'||'" '';
' 
from pg_database t1
where t1.datname not in ('template0', 'template1', 'postgres')
order by datname;
```

I run this SQL code through a batch script and I manage to connect to every database and output their names, but I don't manage to create the roles for each database, it just outputs the text "create role...".

My question is: is it possible to create a role like this? And if yes, what am I doing wrong?

Another way I tried to solve was from inside an anonymous block:

```
do
$$
declare
  rec record;
  db_name text;
begin
  
  for rec in select t1.datname
    from pg_database t1
    where t1.datname not in ('template0', 'template1', 'postgres')
    order by datname
  
  loop
  
    execute 'select ''\c '' '||rec||'
             from pg_database t1
             where t1.datname not in (''template0'', ''template1'', ''postgres'')
             order by datname;
             ';
    
    SELECT current_database()
    into db_name;
    
    raise notice 'Database: %', db_name;

    execute ' create role "'||rec||'_connect'||'" ';
    
    raise notice 'ROLE CREATED';
  end loop;
  
end;
$$
```

However, the record output is between parentheses and I don't know how to escape it to see if it would work through this block.

I would like to know if any of the two solutions make sense and what I need to do to make them work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot connect to a different database inside a statement. A PostgreSQL connection is tied to a single database for its whole lifetime. But you are in luck: since roles are global objects (they are not part of a database, but common to all databases), it does not matter to which database you are connected when you create a role.

Your approach to use dynamic SQL is good. Just skip the attempts to connect to a different database.